# Enable SSL on Sonarqube behind NGINX

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, sonarqube

I have this dockerfile:

```
FROM sonarqube:7.9.3-community
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 80 443 9000

USER sonarqube

CMD ["/bin/bash", "./bin/run.sh"] && ["/usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off";]
```

The requirement is that NGINX and Sonarqube are in the same container.

The container and Sonarqube is UP.

`2023.01.05 14:31:15 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.e.EsClientProvider] Connected to local Elasticsearch: [127.0.0.1:9001] 2023.01.05 14:31:15 INFO  ce[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.0.1:9092/sonar 2023.01.05 14:31:15 WARN  ce[][o.s.db.dialect.H2] H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only. 2023.01.05 14:31:16 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.p.ServerFileSystemImpl] SonarQube home: /opt/sonarqube 2023.01.05 14:31:16 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.c.CePluginRepository] Load plugins 2023.01.05 14:31:17 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.c.ComputeEngineContainerImpl] Running Community edition 2023.01.05 14:31:17 INFO  ce[][o.s.ce.app.CeServer] Compute Engine is operational 2023.01.05 14:31:18 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ce] is up 2023.01.05 14:31:18 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is up`

NGINX does not start.

```
sonarqube@46ee502f9813:/opt/sonarqube$ service nginx status
[FAIL] nginx is not running ... failed!

sonarqube@46ee502f9813:/opt/sonarqube$ service nginx start
[FAIL] Starting nginx: nginx failed!
```

Comment: A container is a wrapper around a single process.  If you need an application and also an Nginx proxy in front of it, it's very routine to run these in two separate containers.  Your proposed `CMD` has syntactic errors, and trying to start additional services inside a running container isn't a sustainable practice.  You might look at tools like Docker Compose that can start up multiple containers together.

Comment: I know it. However, it is a requirement that nginx and sonarqube are in the same container.  I can't get these two services up